# System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Really annoying issue.  The code seems to work fine, but when run, I see this error being thrown up:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsOpen'
>   property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=33664731)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=IsOpen; DataItem='MainViewModel'
>   (HashCode=33664731); target element is 'Popup' (Name='LoginPopup');
>   target property is 'IsOpen' (type 'Boolean')

I understand there is some sort of issue where IsOpen property of LoginPopup binding is being attempted on the MainViewModel and failing because there is no IsOpen property in the MainViewModel.  Fine and good, but the DataContext I'm binding to is not the mainviewmodel, but the LoginPopupViewModel (LoginPopup in the ViewModelLocator class).  Intellisense seems to agree with me that things are bound to the LoginPopupViewModel, as if I type other things in the Binding portion of IsOpen, it complains that, "Cannot resolve property in data context of LoginPopupViewModel", as it should.

Here's a portion of the XAML code:

```
<Popup x:Name="LoginPopup"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=LoginButton}"  
       Placement="Bottom"
       HorizontalOffset="-40" VerticalOffset="35" StaysOpen="False" 
       IsOpen=" {Binding IsOpen}"
       DataContext="{Binding LoginPopup, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
       Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0"
           Margin="0,0,0.333,0"
           Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

I'm not exactly a master of WPF, so I'm probably missing something, or the sytax is wrong here.  Any help would be fantastic!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because `DataContext` binding is after`IsOpen` binding, so when the parser comees across `IsOpen` the `DataContext` is currently `MainViewModel` (set by dependency property inheritance). Then WPF processes the `DataContext={..}` and re-evaluated the `IsOpen` binding.

E.g. 2 bindings ultimately the same, but one showing an error

This gives an error in output, but works

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextB}" DataContext="{Binding B}"></TextBlock>
```

This doesn't give error

```
    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding B}" Text="{Binding TextB}"></TextBlock>
```

---

### Original Answer

---

The error you are getting is because this:

```
IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}"
```

cannot be bound successfully.

You are binding the DataContext of it to `{StaticResource Locator}`, and a property `LoginPopup` on that resource. I am assuming `Locator.LoginPopup` return a `MainViewModel`?

What is `Locator.LoginPopup` and what are you trying to achieve by `IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}"`? Is that a property on some view model?

Comment: Locator is the key for the ViewModelLocator.cs class.
Locator.LoginPopup returns a LoginPopupViewModel and NOT the MainViewModel.

Binding the IsOpen on the popup to the IsOpen property on the LoginPopupViewModel allows me to do a few things, one of which is to open/close a virtual keyboard on the property changing, which does work, which is weird, because this error shows up in the output window on run.

Comment: Actually, that code isn't working, which makes a bit more sense.  The virtual keyboard responds to the text fields on the popup being focused/unfocused.

Comment: What might be happening is IsOpen is binding before DataContext is binding. Try put DataContext binding above IsOpen binding

Comment: Can you share LoginPopupViewModel, as well as that bit of Locator, and the Locator resource declaration?

Comment: You're right on this, and also, I changed the DataContext to  DataContext="{Binding Path=LoginPopup, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}", adding the explicit path, and everything was good.
Thanks!  What a pain XAML can be...

Comment: If it was the right answer, mark it as the answer ;-)

Comment: I didn't downvote...I don't know who did...I don't have enough reputation to vote.